# How to get output in my quicksort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to implement recursion and list comprehension in my quicksort algorithm. But I am not being able to see any output. Can I please get assistance, what lines shall I add to see the output. My logic seems to be correct, and feedback is appreciated.

```
def partition_list(A):
    n = len(A)
    m = A[n - 1]
    #print m
    A_left = [x for x in A if x <= m]
    A_right = [x for x in A if x > m]
    #if len(A_left) >= 2:
    #    return partition_list(A_left)

    Anew = A_left + A_right
    ind = Anew.index(m)
    return Anew,ind
```

This function partition_list is being called in the following function.

```
def quick_sort_helper(A):
    if len(A) > 1:
        Anew,m1 = partition_list(A)
        print Anew
        Aleft = Anew[0:m1]
        Aright = Anew[m1 + 1:len(A)]
        quick_sort_helper(Aleft)
        print Aleft
        quick_sort_helper(Aright)
    else:
        return A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quicksort sorts in place. This means that you have got to make sure that as your partitioning routine finds the final sorted position of the pivot of your choice, you modify (if required) the list *in place*. The partitioning routine is critical to quicksort. I see that you use Python construct like *list compositions*, but in doing so, you seem to forget how quicksort works. It's okay *for starters* to require additional space, but you should really write the partition routine that partitions the given list *in place*.

Your recursive `quick_sort_helper()` function is also confusing. In non-recursive case it returns an array, whereas in recursive case it returns nothing. Python, being (the so-called) *loosely typed* language, does not stop you from doing that.

I have tried to correct these deficiencies in your code while keeping your choices largely intact and it seems to work. It does not work when the list has duplicate elements and that is left as an exercise :-).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def partition_list(A, loIn, hiEx):
    """
    Partitions the given list between given indexes such that the pivot is in its final sorted location.
    Note: uses additional space.
    :param A: the list of integers
    :param loIn: low index, inclusive
    :param hiEx: high index, exclusive
    :return: index pi of pivot =  (A[hiEx- 1]) in the sorted sequence, thus after the function returns, A[pi] = pivot and loIn <= pi < hiEx
    """
    # print "partition call: loIn = %d, hiEx = %d" % (loIn, hiEx)
    n = hiEx - loIn
    pivot = A[hiEx - 1]  # pivot is fixed, last element of the given array
    # print "pivot: %d" % pivot
    slice = A[loIn:hiEx]
    A_left = [x for x in slice if x <= pivot]
    A_right = [x for x in slice if x > pivot]
    Anew = A_left + A_right
    # print Anew
    # copy it back, defeating the purpose of quicksort
    for i in xrange(n):
        A[loIn + i] = Anew[i]
    index = A.index(pivot, loIn, hiEx)
    # print "partition index: %d, element: %d" % (index, A[index])
    return index


def quick_sort_helper(A, loIn, hiEx):
    """
    Implements quicksort recursively. Call this as: quick_sort_helper(a, 0, len(a))
    :param A: the list to sort
    :param loIn: low index, inclusive
    :param hiEx: high index, exclusive
    :return: nothing, sorts list in place.
    """
    if hiEx - loIn > 1:
        m1 = partition_list(A, loIn, hiEx) # A[m1] is in its final sorted position
        quick_sort_helper(A, loIn, m1)
        quick_sort_helper(A, m1 + 1, hiEx)

a = [43, 2, 52, 23, 1, 0, 10, 7, 3]
quick_sort_helper(a, 0, len(a))
print "sorted: ", a # prints: sorted:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 10, 23, 43, 52]
```